# How can I set a specific value to dataframe with a condition without warning in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to modify following **dataframeA** to **dataframeB** with this code.

```
dataframeA[dataframeA < 0.51] = None
```

**dataframeA**

```
   r1   r2  r3
1   1  1.0   1
2   1  0.5   1
3   1  1.0   1
```

**dataframeB**

```
   r1   r2  r3
1   1  1.0   1
2   1  Nan   1
3   1  1.0   1
```

But following warning happens.

```
/usr/local/bin/ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  #!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
```

How can I modify it without this warning?

Comment: You'll need to post more code to reproduce this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just assign `np.nan` instead of `None`:

```
dataframeA[dataframeA < 0.51] = np.nan
```

**EDIT**

If first option not working for you (working in `pandas 0.17.1`, `python 3.4.3`) you could try [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
In [509]: df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x < 0.51 else x)
Out[509]: 
   r1  r2  r3
1   1   1   1
2   1 NaN   1
3   1   1   1
```

Comment: Which `pandas` version are you using?

Comment: Thanks! I can do it without any warning and make correct values.

Comment: However, I'm using pandas 0.17.1.

Comment: I don't know, I don't have any warnings for that. Python `3.4.3`. And even your first case which causes your errors works for me.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. That's why?

Comment: It shouldn't be dependent from python version IMO.

Comment: I see. Anyway, my problem was resolved! Thanks Anton Protopopov!